# Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT CASE Price WHEN '' THEN 0.0 ELSE Price END FROM Table
```

If price empty, it returns 0.0 but if column has value it gives me the error below

**Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.**

How to change my code to handle this case?

Comment: what data type is the Price column?

Comment: Then how can it equal an empty string?  I don't understand your CASE statement.

Comment: I'm selecting it from one table where price is string and inserting it in another table where the price is decimal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE Price WHEN '' THEN 0.0 ELSE CAST(Price AS DECIMAL(...)) END FROM Table
```

Implicit conversions will often take the smallest type possible, so when you hit a larger value it will fail.  Explicitly convert/cast your value to the right type in your CASE/ELSE.

Comment: it works, some of the columns have value like 30.100000000000001 and it fails. Is there any workarounds?